# create multidimenional array from json loop, join specific values in group

Tags: javascript, arrays

trying to loop over json and join specific values and further loop over them.

```
var json = [
    {title: "title1", type: "group1"}
    {name: "name1", type: "in"}
    {name: "name2", type: "out"}
    {name: "name3", type: "out"}
    {title: "title2", type: "group2"}
    {name: "name4", type: "out"}
];

var obj = {},
    count = 0;

for (var i=0; i < json.length; i++){
    if('name' in json[i]){
        var obj[count].push(json[i])
    }else{
        count++;
    }
}
```

how can I join title with appropriate group of names to loop over newly created groups ?

newly created group1 should be

```
[
    {title: "title1", type: "group1"},
    {name: "name1", type: "in"},
    {name: "name2", type: "out"},
    {name: "name3", type: "out"}
]
```

and newly created group2 should be

```
[
    {title: "title2", type: "group2"},
    {name: "name4", type: "out"}
]
```

Comment: your object is not in a valid format

Comment: Your question is not clear. And your json is also not a valid object. Please edit your post to be more clear.

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: You edited it yet the syntax remains invalid and the question is no more clearer than before. If you ran _exactly_ what you've provided, what would you expect it to do?

Comment: So your question is how to group the items in your array based on the position of an item that has a `title` property? Every item after that until the next `title` item is included in the group?

Comment: would it not better to check for `title`?

Comment: @chazsolo yes, I need to group them by title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `title` property for checking if a new group has started. If so, then push the actual object in an array to the result set, otherwise push the actual object to the last array.

```js
var array = [{ title: "title1", type: "group1" }, { name: "name1", type: "in" }, { name: "name2", type: "out" }, { name: "name3", type: "out" }, { title: "title2", type: "group2" }, { name: "name4", type: "out" }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if ('title' in o) {
            r.push([o]);
        } else {
            r[r.length - 1].push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```